# can't set setPositionAsync in expo-av on Android

Tags: android, expo-av

I am using `expo-av` to play Audio sounds in my app but when I call `soundObject.setPositionAsync(pos)` it sets the audio position back to 0 instead of the position that I provided to it, what could be the cause

Comment: I'm having problems with expo 45.00 and expo-av 11.2.3. What versions are you using?

Comment: @stevehs17 sorry for the late reply, I fixed the error already, the cause of the error was I was setting milliseconds number instead of seconds to the `setPositionAsync`, so to fix it make sure the number you're providing to setPositionAsync is in seconds, this is how I did it, `soundObjectRef.current?.setPositionAsync((pos as number) * 1000)` to convert it to seconds

Comment: You're @stevehs17,  lemme know if it works for you

Comment: No, it doesn't work with the versions I mentioned. It does work using earlier versions, so I think it was broken.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue actually stemmed from the number I was passing to the setPositionAsync method. Here's how you can achieve forward and backward functionalities using the Expo Audio-AV plugin:

```
const [isPlaying, setPlaying] = useState(false);
const [soundObject, setSoundObject] = useState(null);
const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
    
    // Loading and playing the audio
    const newSoundObject = new Audio.Sound();
    await newSoundObject.loadAsync({ uri: music });
    await newSoundObject.playAsync();
    setPlaying(true);
    setSoundObject(newSoundObject);
    
    // Listening for playback status updates
    newSoundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status) => {
        if (status.isLoaded) {
            setPosition(status.positionMillis);
            setDuration(status.durationMillis);
            if (status.didJustFinish) {
                newSoundObject.replayAsync();
            }
        }
    });
    
    // Handling forward and backward actions
    const onForward = async () => {
        if (soundObject && isPlaying) {
            const newPosition = position + 10000;
            await soundObject.setPositionAsync(newPosition);
        }
    };
    
    const onBackward = async () => {
        if (soundObject && isPlaying) {
            const newPosition = Math.max(0, position - 10000);
            await soundObject.setPositionAsync(newPosition);
        }
    };
```